# jest.fn() claims not to have been called, but has

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vuex

I'm testing a Vue component that calls a certain action in my Vuex store when a certain parameter is present in the route. I'm mocking the action with `jest.fn()`.

Here's the relevant code from the component:

```
await this.$store.dispatch('someOtherAction');
if (this.$route.params && this.$route.params.id) {
    this.$store.dispatch('selection/selectElement', parseInt(this.$route.params.id, 10));
}
```

Here's the mocked function:

```
someOtherAction = jest.fn();
selectElement = jest.fn(() => console.log("selectElement has been called"));
```

My test:

```
it('selects element if passed in route', async () => {
  const $route = {params: {id: '256'}};
  const wrapper = shallowMount(AbcModel, {
    mocks: {$route},
    store, localVue
  });
  expect(someOtherAction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(selectElement).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

In the output, I can see the 'selectElement has been called'. Clearly it has been called. And yet, `expect(selectElement).toHaveBeenCalled()` fails.

How is this possible? It works fine with another function I mocked. Replacing the order in which I mock the functions doesn't matter. Removing the expectation that the other function gets called doesn't matter either, so it doesn't look like a collision.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by "it works with another function I mocked"?

Comment: The 'someOtherAction' is mocked by jest.fn() too, and it gets called properly. @brian-lives-outdoors answer below seems to explain what the real problem is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> How is this possible?

The `expect` runs and fails before `selectElement` has had a chance to run.

---

### Details

**Message Queue**

JavaScript uses a [message queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Queue).  The current message [runs to completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Run-to-completion) before the next one starts.

**PromiseJobs Queue**

ES6 introduced the [PromiseJobs queue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) which handles jobs "that are responses to the settlement of a Promise".  Any jobs in the PromiseJobs queue run *after the current message completes and before the next message begins*.

**async / await**

`async` and `await` are just [syntactic sugar over promises and generators](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#async-function-definitions-awaited-fulfilled).  Calling `await` on a `Promise` essentially wraps the rest of the function in a callback to be scheduled in PromiseJobs when the `Promise` resolves.

**What happens**

Your test starts running as the current running message.  Calling `shallowMount` loads your component which runs until `await this.$store.dispatch('someOtherAction');` which calls `someOtherFunction` and then essentially queues the rest of the function as a `Promise` callback to be scheduled in the PromiseJobs queue when the `Promise` resolves.

Execution then returns to the test which runs the two `expect` statements.  The first one passes since `someOtherFunction` has been called, but the second fails since `selectElement` has not run yet.

The current running message then completes and the pending jobs in the PromiseJobs queue are then run.  The callback that calls `selectElement` is in the queue so it runs and calls `selectElement` which logs to the console.

---

**Solution**

Make sure the `Promise` callback that calls `selectElement` has run before running the `expect`.

Whenever possible it is ideal to return the `Promise` so the test can `await` it directly.

If that is not possible then a workaround is to call `await` on a resolved `Promise` during the test which essentially queues the rest of the test at the back of the PromiseJobs queue and allows any pending `Promise` callbacks to run first:

```js
it('selects element if passed in route', async () => {
  const $route = {params: {id: '256'}};
  const wrapper = shallowMount(AbcModel, {
    mocks: {$route},
    store, localVue
  });
  expect(someOtherFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  // Ideally await the Promise directly...
  // but if that isn't possible then calling await Promise.resolve()
  // queues the rest of the test at the back of PromiseJobs
  // allowing any pending callbacks to run first
  await Promise.resolve();
  expect(selectElement).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: This is way more informative than I could have hoped for. Thanks you! I ended up removing the async/await, because there seems to be no good reason for them here.